# finding duplicates from multiple datasets in sas by flag

Tags: sas, duplicates

I have a dataset arranged like this:

```
ID  Date  Flag
A  1/1/11 000
A  1/1/11 001
A  1/1/11 010
B  1/2/11 000
B  1/3/11 001
```

I set up a flag to keep track of certain columns and separated the original dataset into four smaller ones.  So one for flag='000', one for '001', one for '010' and '011'.  If I do a unique count by ID and Date, I get say 500 for the original dataset.  But for each separate one by flag, if I add up the total I get say 600.  That means 100 records are duplicates, so in my above example A with 1/1/11 is only 1 unique record, but it appears in the sub dataset of '000', '010', '001'.  So out of the 100 extra duplicates, 3 would be A with date 1/1/11.  Is there a way I can figure this out without looking manually which records by flag are duplicates?

Comment: What do you want the output to be? And ideally any code you have tried to get there.

Comment: hm, proc sql - select distinct id, date, count(*) from table should list you how often you have duplicates when ignoring the flags, alternatively you could use a proc summary but  i am not sure if this is what you want ...